# How to say "X became Y and remained to be Y" more naturally?

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say I want to express that butter became the most consumed spread in 2010 and it remained the most consumed spread until 2015. How do I construct a sentence that expresses that without repeating myself? Something like:

> "Butter became the most consumed spread in 2010 and remained to be the most consumed spread till 2015"

does not feel natural at all and has the "**remained to be the most consumed spread**" part redundantly.

Comment: ***remained*** and ***to be*** can't be used together like this. Use one or the other: *...and **continued to be** the most consumed spread till 2015* OR *...and **remained** the most consumed spread till 2015*. The repetition of ***the most consumed spread*** is stylistically clunky though - you could avoid that with, for example, *...and **remained so** till 2015*.

Comment: Note: You can say all of this more concisely with **"Butter was the most consumed spread from 2010 to 2015."** You lose some emphasis this way (the proposed versions all focus on the start and the duration of its top position) but if that's okay, you lose a lot of dead weight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say something like

> Butter became the most consumed spread in 2010 and **remained so** until 2015

> By 2010, butter had become the most consumed spread and it remained so until 2015

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think ***that way*** is a very natural way to refer back to *[having become / being] **the most consumed spread***. But I don't find it easy to define exactly why I'm okay with ***so*** in this context, but not ***that way***. I'm fine with *John was an argumentative child, and **remained that way** even after adolescence*, but it feels like there's something wrong with *Colchester was the biggest city in Britain when the Romans invaded, and **remained that way** for centuries*. And I don't just mean it's "historically inaccurate". Only ***remained so*** works for me there.

Comment: To me both **remained that way** and **remained so** sound perfectly natural. **remained so** maybe sounds more formal. It might be a difference between British and American English.

Comment: For me there seems to be something weird about usages like *John was taller than his brother Jack as a child, and remained that way as an adult* (where I'm fine with *...and remained **so***). Maybe it's because *to remain **like that*** implies "volition" on the part of the subject, so I find it extra strange when the condition that ***continues to be true*** involves some externally-evaluated comparison with other things, rather than the subject doggedly refusing to change.

Comment: Well now that I've said it over and over in my head **remained that way** sounds weird. I'll defer to your judgement on this one

Comment: *Everything* sounds "weird" after you've kicked it around for a while! If I remember to revisit this interaction, *and* I still feel this inexplicable distinction between *[to remain] **that way / so*** when I look at it again tomorrow, I might raise it as a question over on ELU. It's a bit rarefied for ELL (if indeed it's anything more than my overactive imagination anyway! :)

Comment: I think "remained that", without "so", would also have been natural in that expression. "the most consumed spread" connects better to "that" than it does to "that way".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: The question is ***why*** does "so" or plain "that" work better with "was the most consumed spread", whereas that doesn't seem to be the case with my "was taller" example. Maybe it's just a matter of whether the subject ***was [noun]*** or ***was [adjective].***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that's it.